# Appium TouchAction precise scroll

Tags: appium

I am using the following code to scroll up the view.

```
    TouchAction action =
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(PointOption.point(width / 2, height / 2 + 200))
                    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(duration))
                    .moveTo(PointOption.point(width / 2, height / 2 - 200))
                    .release();
    action.perform();
```

But the distance it scrolls is slightly different every time.
Any way to scroll precisely?

Answer (score -1):

```
for each in range(1, 5):
    driver.swipe(500, 1000, 500, 1700, 400)
    
for each in range(1, 5):
    driver.swipe(500, 1700, 500, 1000, 400)
```